# Characteristic polynomial calculation method

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me, what to put in empty matrices

$$\begin{vmatrix}3-\lambda & -4 & -2 & -4\\
-2 & 5-\lambda & 2 & 4\\
4 & -8 & -3-\lambda & -8\\
2 & -4 & -2 & -3-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}3 & -4 & -2 & -4\\
-2 & 5 & 2 & 4\\
4 & -8 & -3 & -8\\
2 & -4 & -2 & -3
\end{vmatrix}+\lambda(\begin{vmatrix}5 & 2 & 4\\
-8 & -3 & -8\\
-4 & -2 & -3
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}3 & -2 & -4\\
4 & -3 & -8\\
2 & -2 & -3
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}3 & -4 & -4\\
-2 & 5 & 4\\
2 & -4 & -3
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}3 & -4 & -2\\
-2 & 5 & 2\\
4 & -8 & -3
\end{vmatrix}) + \lambda^{2}(\begin{vmatrix}\\
\\
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}\\
\\
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}\\
\\
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}\\
\\
\end{vmatrix})+\lambda^{3}(3+5-3-3)+\lambda^{4}=
 $$

Thanks in avance for help

Comment: You're going to need 6 matrices for that $\lambda^2$ term. Also, I think that should be a minus sign out in front of $\lambda^3$.

Comment: Also, please check the signs of the $\lambda$ and $\lambda^{3}$ coefficients.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Could You tell me more, how to calculate them?

Comment: The easiest method for me is sage

Comment: With apologies for the formatting, they would be [3, -4, -2, 5], [3, -2, 4, -3], [3, -4, 2, -3], [5, 2, -8, -3], [5, 4, -4, -3], and [-3, -8, -2, -3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\p{\phantom{-}}$

Upgrading comment to answer, at request of OP: $$\pmatrix{\p3&-4\cr-2&\p5\cr},\pmatrix{3&-2\cr4&-3\cr},\pmatrix{3&-4\cr2&-3\cr},\pmatrix{\p5&\p2\cr-8&-3\cr},\pmatrix{\p5&\p4\cr-4&-3\cr},\pmatrix{-3&-8\cr-2&-3\cr}$$